# How do I mask an iframe(embedded with yt) with a div to allow my onclick event to trigger instead of it playing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three iframes with yt videos embedded in it. What I want is to be able to disable the controls of yt since once i click the video it starts playing and doesnt fire my onclick event that resizes the iframe's width and height.

This are the things that i think may help:
the use of z-index
masking the iframe with a div
position absolute
(which sadly did not work for me)

```
<div class="main">
<div class="card1" onclick="changeSizeOfVid1()">    

    <iframe id="video1"   width="320px" height="240px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bWPMSSsVdPk">
    </iframe>
</div>
<div class="card2"> 
    <iframe id="video2" onclick="changeSizeOfVid2()"  width="320px" height="240px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0afZj1G0BIE">
    </iframe>
</div>
<div class="card3"> 
    <iframe id="video3" onclick="changeSizeOfVid3()"  width="320px" height="240px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ukg_U3CnJWI">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

[my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ilancemojal/2en6L2ak/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the idea of using z-index, you were on the right track. However, you did not implement this in your fiddle. Here is an example of a possible implementation of such an overlay

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="overlay">
        IM THE OVERLAY
    </div>
    <iframe class="video" width="320px" height="240px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bWPMSSsVdPk">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width:320px;
    height:240px;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    opacity: .8
}

.video{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}
```

JS:

```
element = document.querySelector('.overlay');
element.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert("overlay clicked");
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2en6L2ak/3/